# STM32 linker script for only startup script from FLASH, everything else from RAM

Tags: stm32, linker-scripts

I had an f7 with 1 MB internal flash memory. Thanks to international chip shortage I have to tackle a new challenge:

I now have an f7 with only 64kB internal flash and 16MB external qspi flash memory.

I need the bootloader to update the application in the external qspi flash memory. The bootloader does NOT fit into the internal flash. But I cannot write to the qspi memory while in memory map mode. So I init the external qspi flash memory, copy all of it into the RAM (I do have enough RAM) and run the bootloader from there. Or so i thought.

This is my linker script thought to only let the startup script run from external flash. But linker error **relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.text'** shows up.

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (xr)      : ORIGIN = 0x90F00000, LENGTH = 1M
  RAM (xrw)       : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 316K
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  
  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text.Reset_Handler :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)
    *(.text*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)
    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */ 
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT >FLASH

  
  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
/*    . = ALIGN(4); */
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
/*    . = ALIGN(4); */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM

  

  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Now I would like to get guidance on how to get over this PREL31 limitation or to tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think this error might come from the 16MB limitation of immediate branch instruction on Cortex M7. My guess is that the compiler uses a `B` instruction instead of a `BX`. COuld you post your  C code where you jump from external flash to RAM or the other way around ?

Comment: It is the standard startup script from STM32 Cube IDE that should do the copying. It is in assembler instead of C. Here is the pastebin. Please focus on line 74 ff.
https://pastebin.com/AJXqrkYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is easier way to do this, you only need to change linker script, no need to change startup code

```
/*
******************************************************************************
**
** @file        : LinkerScript.ld
**
** @author      : Auto-generated by STM32CubeIDE
**
**  Abstract    : Linker script for NUCLEO-F413ZH Board embedding STM32F413ZHTx Device from stm32f4 series
**                      1536Kbytes FLASH
**                      320Kbytes RAM
**
**                Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
**                to application requirements.
**
**                Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used
**
**  Target      : STMicroelectronics STM32
**
**  Distribution: The file is distributed as is, without any warranty
**                of any kind.
**
******************************************************************************
** @attention
**
** Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
** All rights reserved.
**
** This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
** in the root directory of this software component.
** If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
**
******************************************************************************
*/

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM); /* end of "RAM" Ram type memory */

_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200 ; /* required amount of heap */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400 ; /* required amount of stack */

/* Memories definition */
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 320K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 1536K
}

/* Sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
  
    /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text.Reset_Handler :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text.Reset_Handler)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);

    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM : {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .init_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .fini_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* Used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections into "RAM" Ram type memory */
  .data :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */
    *(.RamFunc)        /* .RamFunc sections */
    *(.RamFunc*)       /* .RamFunc* sections */
    
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)
    
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */

  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  /* Uninitialized data section into "RAM" Ram type memory */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss section */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough "RAM" Ram  type memory left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM

  /* Remove information from the compiler libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I did not test that, since my code is already running in production. So I did not test your anwer, but I would prefer it since it does not need the setartup code.

Comment: Using my way ISR vector table won't be copied from FLASH to RAM automatically, but it can be done in first line of main function using memcpy((void *)0x20000000, (void *)0x08000000, sizeOfVectorTable) this also can be moved to startup code, after that  SCB->VTOR need to be set to SCB->VTOR = 0x20000000;

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling for 2 days I got it running.
I changed the linker script several times and now the error won't come up again.

I do provide my code here but beware it to be not optimized or bug free.

**TLDR**; Here's my linker script.

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (xr)      : ORIGIN = 0x90F00000, LENGTH = 1M
  RAM (xrw)       : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 316K
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _siisr_vector = LOADADDR(.isr_vector);
  
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sisr_vector = .;    /* create a global symbol at data start */
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _eisr_vector = .;    /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
  
  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text.Reset_Handler :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text.Reset_Handler)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  
  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sitext = LOADADDR(.text);
  
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _stext = .;        /* create a global symbol at code start */
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)
    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sirodata = LOADADDR(.rodata);
  
  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srodata = .;
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */ 
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _erodata = .;
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _siextab = LOADADDR(.ARM.extab);
  
  .ARM.extab :
  { 
    _sextab = .;
    *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    _eextab = .; 
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
  
  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _siexidx = LOADADDR(.ARM);
  
  .ARM :
  {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sipreinit_array = LOADADDR(.preinit_array);
  
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    __preinit_array_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    __preinit_array_end = .;
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
  
  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _siinit_array = LOADADDR(.init_array);
  
  .init_array :
  {
    __init_array_start = .;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    __init_array_end = .;
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
  
  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sifini_array = LOADADDR(.fini_array);
  
  .fini_array :
  {
    __fini_array_start = .;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    __fini_array_end = .;
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  
  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM

  

  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Thanks to [@Guillaume Petitjean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5836577/guillaume-petitjean) I found out I should also work on the startup script, to copy EVERYTHING to Ram. So I modified the startup assembler script as well. Here it is:

```
    .section  .text.Reset_Handler
  .weak  Reset_Handler
  .type  Reset_Handler, %function
Reset_Handler:  
  ldr   sp, =_estack      /* set stack pointer */

/* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM */  
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyDataInit

CopyDataInit:
  ldr  r3, =_sidata
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4
    
LoopCopyDataInit:
  ldr  r0, =_sdata
  ldr  r3, =_edata
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyDataInit
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyIsrInit

CopyIsrInit:
  ldr  r3, =_siisr_vector
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyIsrInit:
  ldr  r0, =_sisr_vector
  ldr  r3, =_eisr_vector
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyIsrInit
  movs r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyCodeInit

CopyCodeInit:
  ldr  r3, =_sitext
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyCodeInit:
  ldr  r0, =_stext
  ldr  r3, =_etext
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyCodeInit
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyRodataInit

CopyRodataInit:
  ldr  r3, =_sirodata
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyRodataInit:
  ldr  r0, =_srodata
  ldr  r3, =_erodata
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyRodataInit
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyArmExtabInit

CopyArmExtabInit:
  ldr  r3, =_siextab
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyArmExtabInit:
  ldr  r0, =_sextab
  ldr  r3, =_eextab
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyArmExtabInit
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyArmInit

CopyArmInit:
  ldr  r3, =_siexidx
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyArmInit:
  ldr  r0, =__exidx_start
  ldr  r3, =__exidx_end
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyArmInit
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyPreinitArrayInit

CopyPreinitArrayInit:
  ldr  r3, =_sipreinit_array
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyPreinitArrayInit:
  ldr  r0, =__preinit_array_start
  ldr  r3, =__preinit_array_end
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyPreinitArrayInit
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyInitArrayInit

CopyInitArrayInit:
  ldr  r3, =_siinit_array
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyInitArrayInit:
  ldr  r0, =__init_array_start
  ldr  r3, =__init_array_end
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyInitArrayInit
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyFiniArrayInit

CopyFiniArrayInit:
  ldr  r3, =_sifini_array
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyFiniArrayInit:
  ldr  r0, =__fini_array_start
  ldr  r3, =__fini_array_end
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyFiniArrayInit
  ldr  r2, =_sbss
  b  LoopFillZerobss
/* Zero fill the bss segment. */  
FillZerobss:
  movs  r3, #0
  str  r3, [r2], #4
    
LoopFillZerobss:
  ldr  r3, = _ebss
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  FillZerobss

/* Call the clock system initialization function.*/
  bl  SystemInit   
/* Call static constructors */
    bl __libc_init_array
/* Call the application's entry point.*/
  bl  main
```

I hope this helps or at least points you in the right direction.